# Allow user in Active Directory 2008 R2 to only send / receive emails

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange, exchange-2010

We need to create a user in Active Directory 2008 R2 that will be able to send receive emails (Exchange 2010). This user should not be able to login to any other server or PC in the domain. We can block him via Log On To... option in Active Directory, and limit him to only access mail server, but does it than mean that he can come to mail server and login in to it via keyboard and mouse?

Is there another way?

Comment: No, they cannot logon to your mail server, because your mail server is physically secure.  Right?

Answer (score 1):

The way to know for sure that he cannot *interactively* logon to your mail server is to

1. Have physical security of the server as Greg stated.
2. Block Remote Desktop Access for regular users.
3. Make sure he is not inside any group that can log onto servers or computers, **or**
4. Make sure he ***is*** in a group that is restricted to not be able to log on to any machines.

For example, in a previous environment I was in, we had a group in AD where we put accounts we didn't want to login to computers, and in our default domain policy we set it so that these accounts cannot login to workstations. They have email access, but cannot logon to computers.

[image]

If we had machines they needed to login to, those machines got put in a special OU with inheritance blocked and their own policy created.

Answer (score 0):

There's another way. You can simply user group policy to restrict who can logon to the server.